# Does the Golden shovel still make rocks give ore?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

The [Thonky wiki](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/golden-and-silver-tools) states that

> If you hit the money rock in your town with the **silver shovel**, the rock might give you ore instead of money.

and also

> The **golden shovel** allows you to bury money in the ground, which has a chance of growing into a money tree.

Does the golden shovel still include the functionality of the silver or is it worth keeping both (and only using the golden shovel when I want to plant money trees)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The golden shovel **does not** give you a chance of receiving ore.

The gold shovel is a regular shovel with an ability to grow money trees. A silver shovel is a regular shovel with an ability to receive ore when hitting the money rock. If you want to do both, then keep one of each.